# How to format JSON from PHP array

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

this is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$output = array();
$kurse = array();
$zusatz = array();
while (isset($_POST['kurs'.$i]))
{
    $kurse[$i] = $_POST['kurs'.$i];

    $i++;
}
$anzahl = count($kurse);


/* Bestimmt den aktuellen Tag*/
$timestamp = time();
$dw = date( "w", $timestamp);
$day = array('So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So');
$rday= array('Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do');
$tag1 = $day[$dw];
$tag2 = $day[($dw+1) % 7];


/* read html */
$homepage = "";
if ($dw >= 1 && $dw <= 5) $homepage .= file_get_contents('xyz'.$tag1.'.html');
if (in_array($tag1, $rday) ) $homepage .= file_get_contents('xyz'.$tag2.'.html');

for( $i = 0; $i < $anzahl; $i++){ 
    if ( strpos( $homepage, $kurse[$i] ) !== false )
    {
        $output[] = $kurse[$i];
    }
}


if(empty($output)) {
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Keinen Kurs gefunden";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
    $response = array();

    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // user node
    $response["get"] = $output;

    echo json_encode($response);
}
exit();

?>
```

My JSON output looks like this:

```
{"success":1,"get":["9b,"6m"]}
```

But it should look like this:

```
{"success":1,
             "get":[{
             "kurs":"9b"
    }
        },
        {
             "kurs":"6m" 
         }
        }]
        }
```

What can I do to format this, because I want to use it in my Android Application.
I think the solution is quite simple but I don't get it, maybe you can help me...

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output[]["kurs"] = $kurse[$i];
```

maybe?

Comment: thanks that's it :) I accept the answer as soon as it's possible thank you very much (Y)!